# Why is my Github pages site only showing my index.html file?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, github-pages

I have code for a website that is displaying perfectly in my codesandbox.io, however to deploy on github pages it needs an index.html. I have my files as a .jsx and .css. I created my index.html file, however it seems to only show that and not my .jsx and .css code.

The following is my current code for my index.html file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>my site</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="DesktopRootRoot1.module.css">
  <style>
    /* Inline styles here */
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>my site</h1>

  <script src="DesktopRootRoot1.jsx"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

It is only showing mysite instead of showing the contents of DesktopRootRoot1.module.css and DesktopRootRoot1.jsx.

Comment: jsx is not understood by browsers, that must be bundled; as for css, I wonder if the file is really in the root dir

Comment: can you show the content of the .jsx file?